# python pandas variable assignment

Tags: python, loops, pandas, variable-assignment

I have an issue with python pandas variable assignment:
I have a tuple like

```
asd=('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')
```

reading the file is just fine:

```
prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(asd[0])
```

but trimming the dataset doesn't work seamlessly:

```
prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[[for x in asd[1:]]]
```

what I want to get is like this:

```
prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[[asd[1],asd[2],asd[3],asd[4],asd[5],asd[6],asd[7],asd[8]]]
```

I've tried:

```
act='\',\''.join(asd[1:])
prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[[act]]
```

but it didn't work because the back slash sign still included

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn it into a list to filter your df:

```
prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[list(asd[1:])]
```

should work:

```
In [157]:
asd=('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')
list(asd[1:])

Out[157]:
['dtime', 'status1', 'age', 'hg', 'sz', 'sg', 'pf', 'rx']
```

The thing to understand here is that your slicing on the tuple will return the tuple with the values in the slice range but to index the df you should pass a list of the column names that you are interested in.